# Between async calls and shared variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that is an event that is fired many times.
When this happens then I need to read a file to populate a variable into a Manager:

```
roomAdded: state => function ( config, room ) {
    const perMng = state.PersistanceManager;
    const perLoader = state.EntityLoaderRegistry.get( 'persistence' );
    if ( perMng.checkArea( config.area ) )
        return;

    var rooms = [];
    var items = [];

    perLoader.setArea( config.area );
    perLoader.fetchAll().then( res => {
        res.rooms.forEach( room => {
//...
            perMng.addArea( config.area, rooms );
```

Now my ***fetchAll*** is not an *async* function and I cannot make it *async* because is what the *EntityLoaderRegistry* wants and I cannot change how it works.

What I need is that starting from the 2° call I would like to ***checkArea*** and do what is into the *if* only after that the previous call finished, that because the previous call could populate the *Map* with the same that is coming next. But I cannot use the *await* key because I want to say again, it's not an *async* function.

Comment: `fetchAll` doesn't need to be an `async` function. Apparently it returns a promise, and that's all you need. Declare `roomAdded` async, and you can `await fetchAll` there.

Comment: @mbojko Even if I made `roomAdded async` I got `perLoader.fetchAll(), SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: As I said, declare `roomAdded` as async function.